# hibernate-5.4.0-upgrade-causes-ij000453-unable-to-get-managed-connection-for java:/xa-Datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, wildfly

We have an application running on Java 8, Wildfly 10, Hibernate 5.0.10 and Spring 4.3.11.

We have upgraded the system to OpenJDK11, Wildfly 16 and Spring 5.1.0 and everything is working as expected.

But when we are trying to upgrade Hibernate to 5.3.6/7/5.4.0, we are facing issues in database connections.

Below are the statements from the logs that I can share.

```
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)

org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/RND_XA_DS
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@16.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at 
 javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:570)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:714)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:613)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
```

1.Increased max-pool-size in standalone-full-ha.xml of wildfly from 35 to 100.

2.Modified SessionFactory cfg properties, changed transaction configurations with properties supported by Hibernate 5.4.0

3.Tried all available flush-strategy values in standalone-full-ha.xml as per 
(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing)

4.Tried all available hibernate.connection.handling_mode for SessionFactory(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database-connection-handling)

5.With the above changes, application EAR didn’t deploy successfully. All issues were prevalent at this point.

6.Changes that helped
a)Transaction configurations in persistence.xml, changed property hibernate.transaction.jta.platform to JBossAS
b)Closed sessions wherever it was opened in the code.

7.Increased Oracle Processes to 800.

8.Updated OJdbc driver to ojdbc8.

```xml
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/RND_XA_DS" pool-name="XYZ" enabled="true" spy="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                        jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
                    </xa-datasource-property>
                    <driver>Oracle11G</driver>
                    <xa-pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>35</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <flush-strategy>Gracefully</flush-strategy>
                        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                        <interleaving>false</interleaving>
                        <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
                        <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>
                    </xa-pool>
                    <security>
                        <security-domain>XYZ</security-domain>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </xa-datasource>
```

#######SESSIONFACTORY properties

```xml
<property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    ${SESSIONFACTORY.DIALECT}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${SESSIONFACTORY.SHOWSQL}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">JBossAS
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.handling_mode">DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION</prop>
                <prop key="jta.UserTransaction">${USER_TRANSACTION}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

EAR gets deployed  on the Wildfly successfully and any operations performed on the Application that has interaction with Database are successful. In no time, Hibernate starts throwing Unable to get Managed Connection

Comment: May be issue is with your code. There might be open connections present in your code which is exhausting your connection pool

Comment: yes, we have closed the connection wherever we were opening it, but no improvements.